# Convert React class components into functional components

Tags: reactjs, phpstorm, webstorm

I am in between converting React class components into functional components which is obviously time-consuming and repetitive stuff.

As a solution to this, I was looking for online tools to help me in this and I found this: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/07/webstorm-2018-2/ which is quite amazing but only with a simple component, as following live template is getting used.

```
function $!NAME(#if($HAS_PROPS)props#end) {
  return $COMPONENT_BODY
}

#if($PROP_TYPES)
$!{NAME}.propTypes = $PROP_TYPES
#end

#if($DEFAULT_PROPS)
  $!{NAME}.defaultProps = $DEFAULT_PROPS
#end
```

is there any live template for the complex class to functional component conversion or any online tool?

Any suggestions would really be appreciated!

Comment: I think you underappreciate the complexity of development. It is really hard (if not impossible at this point) to automatically convert complex logic from one format to another. If this was possible then we would be able to convert entire codebases from one language to another and stop maintaining 50-year-old COBOL code :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest looking at [Glean](https://github.com/wix/vscode-glean) VSCode extension.
But note that it has some limitations: for example, Glean shows a warning that '*all instance methods are going to be dropped*' before allowing to refactor
Even on the simplest code it mangles both the resulting component code and the imports.

We've investigated a possibility to enhance the **Convert class components into functional components** intention to works with complex classes, but it would require writing a lot of code if a class contains even the simplest helper methods. Plus there are cases when the semantic is not clear, things are not convertible (for example,     `setState` has a `callback` argument, but `useState` [does not](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usestate-callback/), etc. And converting react lifecycle methods to hooks seems like something we should not touch until there is a specification of hooks' behavior / the hooks API is extended to have closer to a 1-1 relation with class methods.